# Remove files via names contained in an array with a foreach loop and Remove-Item in Powershell

Tags: powershell

With Powershell, I'm trying to delete some files in a directory. I have an array, which contains the names of the files I want to keep (They are in the $NameOfFilesToKeep array). All other files have to be deleted. Here's the code I'm using :

```
####### YOU HAVE TO MODIFY THIS SETTINGS #######


$GenericIDandNameOfProject = "[19123]PARIS EST"  #If the name of your files is something like this [19123]PARIS EST_XXX.XML , it should be equal to "[19123]PARIS EST"

$Entries = "10
8
9
16"   #Be careful, this " should be on the same line as the last number!


####### END OF THE SETTINGS YOU HAVE TO MODIFY #######



$IDofInterestingElements = $Entries.split("`n")


for ($i=0; $i -lt $IDofInterestingElements.Length-1; $i++) {
    $IDofInterestingElements[$i] = $IDofInterestingElements[$i].Substring(0,$IDofInterestingElements[$i].Length-1)
}

Write-Output ("Soooo, you want " + $IDofInterestingElements.Length + " files at the end")

$NameOfFilesToKeep = @()

foreach ($ID in $IDofInterestingElements) {
    $NameOfFilesToKeep += $GenericIDandNameOfProject + "_" + $ID + ".XML"
}


$CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location).path

foreach ($file in dir $CurrentDirectory) {
    if ($NameOfFilesToKeep.Contains($file.name)) {
        Write-Output (${file})
    }
    else {
        Remove-Item "${CurrentDirectory}\${file}"
    }
}

Start-Sleep 100
```

The name of the files are "[19123]PARIS EST_XXX.XML" where XXX is a number, like [19123]PARIS EST_10.XML

It simply doesn't work. I think I miss something important with the Remove-Item part. What might be wrong with my code?

### Edit

I have added the full code for a better comprehension.

Comment: please add a few lines from `$NameOfFilesToKeep` so that we can see what the code is trying to work with.

Comment: also, try replacing this >>> `Remove-Item "${CurrentDirectory}\${file}"`<<< with this >>> `Remove-Item -LiteralPath $File.FullName -WhatIf` <<<

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, I edited the post to add the rest of the code. Maybe the problem is in the generation of the names to put in the $NameOfFilesToKeep array (your solution doesn't work for me, but there is no error raised)

Comment: if you want to let someone know that you have replied to their comment, you need to add an `@` symbol and the username at the start of your comment. [*grin*]

Comment: your code is grabbing EVERYTHING in the target directory, then removing from that list ONLY the file names to keep. you likely only want file names, not directories. if so, then you should add `-File` to your `foreach ($file in dir $CurrentDirectory) {` call. ///// plus, the `"${CurrentDirectory}\${file}"` is needlessly complex. you already have the full path to the file in `$File.FullName` ... so use it. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have not been able to find out WHY your code doesn't delete the files. [*blush*] however, i can get it to work if i replace the `foreach` loop with this version ...

```
foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $CurrentDirectory -File)) {
    if ($NameOfFilesToKeep.Contains($file.name)) {
        Write-Output $File.FullName
    }
    else {
        Remove-Item -LiteralPath $File.FullName -WhatIf
    }
}
```

remember to remove the `-WhatIf` when you are ready to actually delete things.

Comment: @Poussinou - you are most welcome! glad to help a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to remove $file.name.  Otherwise $file will stringify to the whole path (this varies with powershell version).  *Note that IList.Contains() (with arrays) is case sensitive* https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.system-collections-ilist-contains?view=netframework-4.8.

```
$nameoffilestokeep = echo file1.txt file2.txt

$CurrentDirectory = (Get-Location).path

foreach ($file in dir $CurrentDirectory) {
    if ($NameOfFilesToKeep.Contains($file.name)) {
        Write-Output (${file})
    }
    else {
        Remove-Item "${CurrentDirectory}/$($file.name)" -whatif
    }
}
```

Actually, your version works for me in ps5 for windows.  But we don't know what $nameoffilestokeep looks like.  It should be an array of strings.

EDIT:
The new code should mostly work, except with .substring() you're chopping 1 character off the end of each string.  The square brackets in the filenames are going to give you trouble, because they're part of wildcards in powershell.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I added the full code in the original post, to see how I put items in $NameOfFilesToKeep.
I have PS5.1 on my computer.